# how to create criteria join in hibernate and instance class

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to ask how to create criteria join in hibernate from this example. How to create instance class?

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(????.class);

table POI {
    int poiID,
    string name,
    int regionID
}

table POIDetail {
    int id,
    string poiID,
    string description
}
```

query :

```
select a.poiID, a.name, b.description 
from POI a, POIDetail b 
where a.poiID = b.poiID and a.regionID = ?;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class

```
table POI {
    int poiID,
    string name,
    int regionID
}

table POIDetail {
    int id,
    POI poi,
    string description
}
```

Hibernate Criteria :

```
public List<POIDetail> getPoiDetailByRegion(int regionID) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(PoiDetail.class);
    criteria.createAlias("poi", "p");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("p.regionId", regionId));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

So you can get all information from **POIDetail** class.